# Can't echo the retrieved value from database in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am new to CI and i am trying to display some data from the database. i have tried but it gives the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_menu() in C:\xampp\htdocs\eat\application\views\includes\header.php on line 55" 
here is my model

```
function menu_item() {


    $this->db->select('c_name');
    $this->db->from('menu_category');
    $this->db->where('c_type', '2');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result();
}
```

and controller

```
function menu_display()
    {
        $data   = array();
        $this->load->model('shared_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('acl');
        $data['result'] = $this->shared_model->menu_item();
        $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
    }
```

and view

```
<li><a href="#">Flights</a>

                        <ul>


                           <?php echo get_menu(); ?>

                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a><span class="navarrow"></span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 03</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a><span class="navarrow"></span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 02</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: I don't see any get_menu() function. I think you might be missing a helper function with this name.

Comment: and how to resolve this please help i am new and new mean just started yesterday.

Comment: @vivek please tell me how to over come this problem and what kind of helper function i need to define?

Answer (score 0):

In your menu_item() function:

```
return $query->result_array();
```

In view (simplified):

```
<?php foreach($result as $v){ echo $v['c_name'].' '; } ?>
```

Comment: now it says "A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: includes/header.php

Line Number: 55"

and on line 55 i have used your code for the view

Comment: Be sure to change your menu_item() function as I suggested above. In controller function menu_display, right below `$data['result'] = $this->shared_model->menu_item();`put `print_r($data['result']); exit;`--> Is anything returned from the database?

Comment: In your model, are you still doing this: `return $result = $query->result();`? It should be `return $query->result_array();`.

Comment: Yes doing exactly what you said still getting the error/

Comment: With the code I provided, $data['result'] cannot be false/undefined - it should at the very least contain an empty array (in the case where your model's db query does not return any results).

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a helper called menu_helper.php and a function named get_menu() in this helper.

The function will look like this:

```
function get_menu($menu_items)
{
    if(!empty($menu_items)) {
        foreach($menu_items as $item) {
            echo $item['c_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

The pass $result to get_menu function in your view:

```
get_menu($result);
```

Comment: i created a file pasted your code and then it says Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_menu() in C:\xampp\htdocs\eat\application\views\includes\header.php on line 55
the line 55 is the echo line

Comment: you should put this file in helpers folder which is inside application folder. Load the helper like this: $this->load->helper(menu_helper)

Comment: where to load this file in controller.?

Comment: loaded it in controller and still the error Call to undefined function get_menu() came.

Comment: If you are loading the helper properly, this shouldn't come. Can you try a bit more? Or, paste your code in paste bin and give me the link.

Comment: here is the link of these files https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4Y5T0Re6tD5VzlqckUzUVNvSXc/edit

Comment: requested permission for the doc you shared

Comment: sory try this link... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Y5T0Re6tD5VzlqckUzUVNvSXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: how to call this function in controller and then pass it in view can you please tell @vivek